# XSLT - XML to XML Transformation with xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

The XML I'm trying to transform looks as follows. I can't post the actual file as it contains sensitive information.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <TimesheetDetails>
     <timeAllocations>
       <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
         <activity>
           <displayText> Value </displayText>
         </activity>
       </TimeAllocationEntryDetails> 
       <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
          <activity>
           <displayText> Value </displayText>
         </activity>
       </TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
       <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
          <activity>
           <displayText> Value </displayText>
         </activity>
       </TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
       <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
          <activity>
           <displayText> Value </displayText>
         </activity> 
       </TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
     </timeAllocations> 
    </TimesheetDetais>
```

Here's a simple XSLT stylesheet I wrote to extract the data from the child nodes. It works as expected, however it only returns data from ONE of the TimesheetEntryDetails

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/TimeSheetDetails">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="timeAllocations"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="timeAllocations">

<xsl:for-each select="TimeAllocationEntryDetails">
      <xsl:for-each select=".">  
          <DisplayText>
          <xsl:value-of select="displayText"/>
          </DisplayText>
      </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output should look something like

```
<DisplayText>
   SomeData
</DisplayText>
```

one for each TimeSheetAllocationEntryDetails node under timeheetAllocations.

Any help appreciated. I'm new to XSLT and I have a feeling I'm not using the xsl:for-each construct correctly.

Output I'm getting looks like (just one element ... the first)

```
<DisplayText>
       SomeData
 </DisplayText>
```

Comment: Without further nodes instead of ".. some child nodes" it's difficult to guess what should be transformed to what...

Comment: I will add some actual node names.

Answer (score 3):

#### Sample output not matching what I get

Your sample output does not match mine.  You say you're getting:

```
<DisplayText>
    SomeData
</DisplayText>
```

When I run your XSL against your sample input XML, I get this:

```
<DisplayText/><DisplayText/><DisplayText/><DisplayText/>
```

I do indeed get one `<DisplayText>` element per input `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` element, as expected.  These elements are also empty, as expected.

#### Breaking down issues in your code

Your first template is in order:

```
<xsl:template match="/TimeSheetDetails">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="timeAllocations"/>
</xsl:template>
```

`<TimeSheetDetails>` is indeed the topmost element in the input XML, and this has `<timeAllocations>` children.

The next template has some problems:

```
<xsl:template match="timeAllocations">
    <xsl:for-each select="TimeAllocationEntryDetails">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">  
            <DisplayText>
                <xsl:value-of select="displayText"/>
            </DisplayText>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

One stylistic issue is the use of `<xsl:for-each select="TimeAllocationEntryDetails">` here.  Since the `<timeAllocations>` element has `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` children, it is more common to use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, optionally specifying `select="TimeAllocationEntryDetails"`, and then define a template for handling these elements -- much as you do in your first template.

That aside, you process each `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>`, and then within each one of these, you have another `<xsl:for-each select=".">`.  This selects `.`, which means "the context element" -- which is just the current `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` again.  This second nested `for-each` is thus wholly unnecessary.

Within the `for-each` structure, you next have:

```
        <DisplayText>
            <xsl:value-of select="displayText"/>
        </DisplayText>
```

So for each `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` element, we create one `<DisplayText>` element.  We have four `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` elements in the input XML, and four `<DisplayText>` elements in the output XML -- so this works just fine.

Within that `<DisplayText>` element, you try to get the value of the `<displayText>` element that is a child of the `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` context element.  Since no such `<displayText>` element exists, this `value-of` produces nothing -- so the output `<DisplayText>` elements are all empty.

#### UPDATE

Your edit changed your input XML.  This is what I was responding to:

```
<TimesheetDetails>
    <timeAllocations>
        <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
            .. some child nodes 
        </TimeAllocationEntryDetails> 
        <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
            .. some child nodes 
        </TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
        <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
            .. some child nodes 
        </TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
        <TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
            .. some child nodes 
        </TimeAllocationEntryDetails>
    </timeAllocations> 
</TimesheetDetails>
```

With your new input XML, the `<displayText>` elements now *exist*, but not at the XPath you're using in `<xsl:value-of select="displayText"/>`.  This again is looking for the value of the `<displayText>` element that is an immediate child of the context element, which in your case would be the `<TimeAllocationEntryDetails>` element.  Since `<displayText>` is *not* an immediate child, this call to `value-of` produces nothing.

If you want to just output the string value of the entire context XML structure, you could just use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` instead.

If you want only the value of the `<displayText>` element to the exclusion of anything else, either 1) specify the exact XPath to this element, as `<xsl:value-of select="activity/displayText"/>`, or 2) use the `descendant::` axis, as `<xsl:value-of select="descendant::displayText"/>`, or 3) use the `//` shorthand for `descendant::`, as `<xsl:value-of select=".//displayText"/>` (note that you need the `.`, or `//displayText` equates to the collection of all `displayText` elements anywhere in the entire file).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the `.`(current node) with a `*`(all child elements of the current node) in the second `for-each`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="TimeAllocationEntryDetails">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">          <!-- here -->
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: To be clear, the XPath expression `*` designates all *child* elements of the current node.  Saying simply "all elements" is open to misinterpretation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I changed that accordingly.